# Spacing words in a line to be justified on left and right side

Tags: spacing

I am writing a resume, and at the top header of the document I am displaying my email, phone number, and address. Each field is separated by a bullet, and I am wondering if it is possible to adjust the spacing between the bullets to make the line extend to the right margin?

It's difficult for me to describe what I'm trying to do, so I've created a mockup. I can adjust the spacing between the words, but that would add the spacing between all words, not just the bullets.

Here's the code I'm using for this line, along with the bullets. Thank you!

```
\noindent
\href{mailto:user@host.com}{john\mbox{}@\mbox{}emaildomain.com}\sbull
\textsmaller{+}1 (202) 555-1212\sbull
3481 Main Street\sbull
New York,\thinspace{\sc NY}\sbull
12345\sbull
USA
```

[image: Description of spacing]

Comment: Try \hfill, or several in one line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped if The OP had provided an MWE, but I tried to fill in the gaps.  The key to the fix was to install `\hfill` around the `\sbull` macro.  It can be done manually on a case by case basis, or if `\sbull` is not needed elsewhere, it can be done automatically as

```
\let\svsbull\sbull
\def\sbull{\hfill\svsbull\hfill}
```

Here is the MWE.  The line below the text shows the marginal extent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\sbull{$\bullet$}
\def\textsmaller#1{\bgroup\small#1\egroup}
\let\svsbull\sbull
\def\sbull{\hfill\svsbull\hfill}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\href{mailto:user@host.com}{john\mbox{}@\mbox{}emaildomain.com}\sbull
\textsmaller{+}1 (202) 555-1212\sbull
3481 Main Street\sbull
New York,\thinspace{\sc NY}\sbull
12345\sbull
USA

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)  I wasn't familiar with MWE, and will keep that in mind when I post again. Thanks for taking the time to answer this. - William

Comment: @William  MWE is a "minimum working example", and it means that it is most helpful if the example you provide starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  Welcome to the site.